# sleep the thread using milliseconds instead of using seconds in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

I have a boost condition variable which I am using to sleep a thread.

```
    boost::condition_variable m_cond;
```

Currently I am using like this in which I am passing the lock and the seconds to which it has to sleep. Currently it will sleep for 10 seconds

```
if(!m_cond.timed_wait(lock, boost::posix_time::seconds(10))){


}
```

Is there any way to do same thing in milliseconds? Instead of passing that as a seconds, can I pass the number of milliseconds it has to wait? Suppose if I need to wait for 2 seconds, then I would like to pass 2000 ms as the value. This doesn't work -

```
long ms = 2000;
if(!m_cond.timed_wait(lock, ms)){


}
```

Is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: `boost::posix_time::milliseconds` instead of `boost::posix_time::seconds`

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/thread/time.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(!m_cond.timed_wait(lock, boost::posix_time::milliseconds(2000)))
```